# storing long text pieces

Tags: php, mysql, search, storage

I am coding an online notes web application, and want to have support for notes ranging from 200 characters to very long ones (~more than 10000 characters). These notes should be searchable.

- How can I store the text note in my database, will it slow down my application if I use the same table for all notes?
- Should I implement multiple types of notes (like short, long, very long, etc) and use different tables for them?
- Should I use files instead of database entries for notes as long as 5000 characters?
- How can I process a text search through these notes (in case I store them on different tables and/or files)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

10,000 characters isn't all that large for MySQL. You can use a TEXT column to store up to 2<sup>16</sup> bytes. That's enough if your text is ASCII. If it's Unicode, then you can use a LONGTEXT field to store up to 2<sup>32</sup> bytes per record.

Designing separate tables for different note lengths is, I think, a bad idea. It will make querying much more difficult.

MySQL also supports [full text searching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html). If you create an ISAM table, you can create a FULLTEXT index on the notes field to speed up searches (quite a bit). Search for *FULLTEXT* in the [manual page for CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html) for details.

Answer (score 4):

Use one table, with one `TEXT` column. That's perfectly suitable, MySQL can handle that without breaking a sweat. Put a `FULLTEXT` index on it for medium-advanced searching capabilities.

Comment: A TEXT column can handle notes up to 65536 bytes. OP is storing notes over 10,000 characters. Depending on the character set and how much over 10K, it might be worthwhile going with a LONGTEXT column instead. Also, FULLTEXT is only available with ISAM (and InnoDB as of MySQL 5.6) tables.

Comment: Good addendum, couldn't look up the details in the documentation when I wrote this.

Answer (score 2):

- No
- No
- No
- Use full text search in mysql or just a like '%search%' which would be a bit slower.

This kind of size of document is a doddle to a modern database, just built it and dont worry about it.